# How to Send a Sms and wait for reply in Python using Twilio?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to create a vaccine appointment scheduler in Python. I am reading data currently from an Excel Sheet which has the time slots and the phone numbers and I am sending them the text as:

```
import csv              
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = ''
auth_token = ''
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
name='Test'
f = open(name+'.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)   
data = []

for row in csv_f: 
    data.append(row)

f.close()
for row in data:
    if (data):
        firstname = row[0]
        
        phone_number = row[3]
        print(phone_number)
        time = row[5]
        confirmation = row[6]
        print(confirmation)
        nl = '\n'
        message = client.messages \
                        .create(
                            body=f"{firstname},\n\nCOVID Vaccine appointment confirmation on March 17th, {time} at .\n\nYour confirmation number is {confirmation}. Please show this message at your arrival.\n\nWe have LIMITED parking, please show up on time.\n\nYou MUST register using the form below before your appointment.\n\n\n ",
                            from_='+1',
                            to=f'+1{phone_number}'
                        )

    print(message.sid)
    #print (firstname,lastname,phone_number,time)
```

Now, I want to have a feature where I can ask the user to send 1 to confirm and 2 to cancel. How do I achieve that? Any documentation or code snippets would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Twilio docs on [How to Receive and Reply to SMS and MMS Messages in Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python).

The basic flow being:

- Send out the SMS (your code) and store to whom you've send it and their appointment details in some kind of database/cache.
- Receive SMS via your new endpoint, this does a look up in the database/cache and marks them confirmed or cancelled.

For this to work you would need to connect the webhook of your `from` number in Twilio to the new endpoint for receiving SMS which you need to create.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and I just now figured out how to do this entirely from the Twilio REST Python library.

**TLDR:** If you want to use the REST helper library, use `client.messages.list(from_='phone number here')`

---

[The documentation has examples using Flask and TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python), which seems like the "right" way to do this, but here is how to do it with the Python library.

Library documentation is here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-python/index.html

## How to see all sent and received messages

If you just want to see all messages, sent and received, you can use `twilio.rest.Client.messages.list()`. Here is an example:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = ''
auth_token  = ''
service_SID = ''
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

# See all messages, both sent and received
for message in client.messages.list():
    print(message.to, message.body)
```

Here, `client.messages.list()` returns a list of type `twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.message.MessageInstance`.

Here, `message.to` is a string that returns the phone number, and `message.body` is the content of the message. You can also use `message.direction` to see if it's an inbound or outbound message,

You can also use `client.messages.stream()` to get a generator, which works in a similar manner.

## How to see all messages received from a specific number

Per [this page in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-and-modify-message-history-python), we can actually pass arguments to `list()` to filter by sender number, receiver number, and date sent:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = ''
auth_token  = ''
service_SID = ''
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

# See all messages, both sent and received
for message in client.messages.list(from_=''):
    print(message.body)
```

(Note this is a parameter name `from_` and not the python keyword `from`.)